# When to use the function 'structure()' in R?

Tags: r, serialization, types

In R, what is the difference between a1 and b1 :

```
a1 = structure(list(c("A","B"), c("X","Y")))
b1 = list(c("A","B"), c("X","Y"))
```

I'm asking this question because I'm trying to understand how the dataset `UCBAdmissions` has been built. We have

```
structure(c(512, 313, 89, 19, 353, 207, 17, 8, 120, 205, 202, 
391, 138, 279, 131, 244, 53, 138, 94, 299, 22, 351, 24, 317), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L, 6L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Admit = c("Admitted", "Rejected"
), Gender = c("Male", "Female"), Dept = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F")), .Names = c("Admit", "Gender", "Dept")), class = "table")
```

Without using `structure` for .Dimnames, it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: it worked for me, are you using named lists when replacing structure with list? .Names is being used inside of the .Dimnames structure

Comment: If you want to know the difference between two objects in R use `all.equal`, e.g.,  `all.equal(a1, b1)`. If you want to know what a function does use `help` e.g., `help(structure)`.

Comment: For clarification, the question is basically "Why is `structure(list(...))` used in `.Dimnames = structure(list(Admit = c("Admitted", "Rejected"
), Gender = c("Male", "Female"), Dept = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F"))` instead of simply `list(...)`?"  Is that correct?

Comment: And if you want copy/pasteable data creation like that UCBAdmissions data, use `dput()`. E.g., `dput(UCBAdmissions)`.

Comment: In a nutshell, it's because that's how the parser requires it to be.

Answer (score 1):

`structure` is a function to associate *attributes* with a given R object. For example:

```
a <- 1:4
b <- structure(a, x="an attribute")
b

#[1] 1 2 3 4
#attr(,"x")
#[1] "an attribute"
```

This does the same thing as assigning attributes to an object with `attr(*) <-`:

```
b <- a
attr(b,"x") <- "an attribute"
b

#[1] 1 2 3 4
#attr(,"x")
#[1] "an attribute"
```

Certain common features you probably use all the time are implemented as attributes. These include `names`, `dim` (array dimensions) and `dimnames` (row and column names, and multidimensional extensions thereof).

```
structure(1:4, dim=c(2,2), dimnames=list(c("row1","row2"), c("col1","col2")))

#     col1 col2
#row1    1    3
#row2    2    4
```

Another one is an object's S3 `class`.

```
obj <- structure(1:4, class="myclass")
print.myclass <- function(x) {
    cat("An object of class 'myclass'\n")
    print.default(c(x))
    invisible(x)
}
obj

#An object of class 'myclass'
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

In your case, `UCBAdmissions` is a `table` object, which is basically a multidimensional array with optional names for each of the dimensions. The output you have there is from `dput`, which is more verbose than strictly necessary. This is for conservative reasons, to ensure that the output can always be parsed correctly. You can simplify it a bit:

```
# from dput(UCBAdmissions)
x <- structure(c(512, 313, 89, 19, 353, 207, 17, 8, 120, 205, 202, 391,
                 138, 279, 131, 244, 53, 138, 94, 299, 22, 351, 24, 317),
    .Dim = c(2L, 2L, 6L),
    .Dimnames = structure(list(Admit = c("Admitted", "Rejected"),
                               Gender = c("Male", "Female"),
                               Dept = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")),
                          .Names = c("Admit", "Gender", "Dept")),
    class = "table")

# simplified
y <- structure(c(512, 313, 89, 19, 353, 207, 17, 8, 120, 205, 202, 391,
                 138, 279, 131, 244, 53, 138, 94, 299, 22, 351, 24, 317),
    dim = c(2, 2, 6),
    dimnames = list(Admit = c("Admitted", "Rejected"),
                    Gender = c("Male", "Female"),
                    Dept = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")),
    class = "table")

identical(x, y)
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

`structure` is not needed for `.Dimnames`:

```
foo <- structure(c(512, 313, 89, 19, 353, 207, 17, 8, 120, 205, 202, 
                   391, 138, 279, 131, 244, 53, 138, 94, 299, 22, 351, 24, 317),
                 .Dim = c(2L,
                          2L, 6L),
                 .Dimnames = structure(list(Admit = c("Admitted", "Rejected"
                                                      ),
                                            Gender = c("Male", "Female"),
                                            Dept = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")),
                                       .Names = c("Admit", "Gender", "Dept")),
                 class = "table")
bar <- structure(c(512, 313, 89, 19, 353, 207, 17, 8, 120, 205, 202,
                   391, 138, 279, 131, 244, 53, 138, 94, 299, 22, 351, 24, 317),
                 .Dim = c(2L,
                          2L, 6L),
                 .Dimnames = list(Admit = c("Admitted", "Rejected"
                                            ),
                                  Gender = c("Male", "Female"),
                                  Dept = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")),
                 class = "table")
all.equal(foo, bar)
## TRUE
```

More generally, `structure` with no `...` arguments should be a no-op and is in fact a no-op on all the examples I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

As can be seen, the following creates a table with 3 dimensions Admit (2 levels), Gender (2 levels) and Dept (6 levels) and orders the 2*2*6=24 elements in the vector into the following structure in column major order.

```
d <- structure(c(512, 313, 89, 19, 353, 207, 17, 8, 120, 205, 202, 
         391, 138, 279, 131, 244, 53, 138, 94, 299, 22, 351, 24, 317),
         .Dim = c(2L, 2L, 6L),
         .Dimnames = structure(list(Admit = c("Admitted", "Rejected"),
         Gender = c("Male", "Female"),
         Dept = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")),
         .Names = c("Admit", "Gender", "Dept")),
         class = "table")
str(d)
table [1:2, 1:2, 1:6] 512 313 89 19 353 207 17 8 120 205 ...
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
      ..$ Admit : chr [1:2] "Admitted" "Rejected"
      ..$ Gender: chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
      ..$ Dept  : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

d
, , Dept = A

          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  512     89
  Rejected  313     19

, , Dept = B

          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  353     17
  Rejected  207      8

, , Dept = C

          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  120    202
  Rejected  205    391

, , Dept = D

          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  138    131
  Rejected  279    244

, , Dept = E

          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted   53     94
  Rejected  138    299

, , Dept = F

          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted   22     24
  Rejected  351    317
```

Comment: (Indented and reformatted your code into 72/80-character lines, so it can be read)